# Microsoft Dynamics NAV - create new entry of SalesOrder (Simple.OData.Client)

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-nav, simple.odata

I'm trying to post a new entry of SalesOrder via OData web services using Simple.OData.Client in Microsoft Dynamics NAV.

This **works**:

```
        ODataClientSettings settings = new ODataClientSettings();
        settings.BaseUri = new Uri(Constants.ODataServiceEndpoint);
        settings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Constants.SecureUserName, Constants.SecureUserPassword);
        client = new ODataClient(settings);

        var items = await client
            .For("SalesOrder")
            .FindEntriesAsync();
```

Unfortunately, this **doesn't work** and I don't have an idea why:

```
        var product = await client
                .For<SalesOrder>("SalesOrder")
                .Set(CreateDummyOrder())
                .InsertEntryAsync();
```

I get this exception:

```
     Exception caught : Simple.OData.Client.WebRequestException: Internal Server Error
     at Simple.OData.Client.RequestRunner.PostExecute(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
     at Simple.OData.Client.RequestRunner.ExecuteRequestAsync(ODataRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Simple.OData.Client.ODataClient.ExecuteRequestWithResultAsync[T](ODataRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func`2 createResult, Func`1 createEmptyResult, Func`1 createBatchResult)
     at Simple.OData.Client.ODataClient.InsertEntryAsync(FluentCommand command, Boolean resultRequired, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Simple.OData.Client.BoundClient`1.InsertEntryAsync(Boolean resultRequired, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Try looking through the Event Viewer logs on the NAV server, for more information about the "Internal Server Error"...
It could be related to the NAV internal logic, such as a product has been marked as 'Blocked' for posting, for example.  Not necessarily related to a technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure out the problem.

For everyone who's gonna deal with it, it's necessary to use **OData V4 URL**. Although I'm not sure why is the posting not working with OData V3 URL. After that, you have to enabled Manual Nos.

Comment: How to use OData V4 URL? and How to enable Manual Nos?